# Cascading two dropdowns in asp.net mvc using ajax not working

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to show a list of coaches in a dropdown when a city is selected. Here, are my 2 dropdowns;

```
<td>
    <select id="ddlCity" class="form-control" onchange="getCoaches();">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cities)
        {
           <option value="@item.id">@item.City_Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</td>
<td>
   <select id="ddlCoach" class="form-control">

   </select>
</td>
```

Here, is the function that returns the list of coaches. it is working fine and returns the list of coaches;

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getCoaches(string cityId)
{
    int intcityId = Convert.ToInt32(cityId);

    var coaches = db.tbl_Coordinators.Where(x => x.fk_cityid == intcityId).ToList();

    return Json(coaches);
}
```

Here, is the ajax code. Instead, of populating the coaches drop down, it jumps to the error.

```
function getCoaches(){

    $('#ddlCoach option').remove();
    alert('in function');
    var selected_City = $("#ddlCity :selected").text();
    var selected_City_Value = $("#ddlCity :selected").val();
    alert(selected_City_Value);
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/getCoaches",
        datatype: "Json",
        data: { cityId: selected_City_Value },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            console.log(data);
            alert('success' + data);

            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#ddlCoach').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.Cordinator_Name + '</option>');
            });

        }
        ,error: function(jqXHR, status,err){

            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried many other solutions but none of them work. I guess something is wrong in the ajax code and I dont know how to debug it.

Comment: You should do `alert(err);` to display what error you are getting

Comment: what is displayed in the console when you do `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write your `getCoaches` controller `POST` method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getCoaches(int cityId)
{
    var coaches = db.tbl_Coordinators.Where(x => x.fk_cityid == cityId).ToList();
    var coachSelectList = new SelectList(coaches , "Id", "Cordinator_Name"); // ensure that your coach model class primary key name is `Id`
    return Json(coachSelectList);
}
```

Then write your `GetCoaches` javaScript method as follows:

```
function getCoaches(){
    var ddlCoachSelector = $('#ddlCoach');
    ddlCoachSelector.empty();

    var selectedCity = $("#ddlCity").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/getCoaches",
        data: { cityId: selectedCity },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.length> 0){
                 ddlCoachSelector.append($("<option>").val("").text("Select Coach"));
                 $(data).each(function(index, item) {
                       ddlCoachSelector.append($("<option>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                 });
            } else{
                ddlCoachSelector.append($("<option>").val("").text("Coach list empty!"));
            }

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status,err){

            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But First, the POST method was showing error so I added "New" Keyword here; var coachSelectList = new SelectList(coaches, "Id", "Cordinator_Name"); Second, When I select a city, this line runs; ddlCoachSelector.append($("<option>").val("").text("Select Coach")); but no data is displayed beneath, Although the post method is returning the data fine.

Comment: @AghaHasan can you give me remote access please?

Comment: Yeah sure. Teamviewer?